# Is there a smarter way to call a function that returns a promise if that function needs to be called around 250 times?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to send back JSON containing the current time on all timezones. I have a function that returns a promise. The point of this function is after calculating the UTC offset of a timezone, to make it into the 24-hour format. Here is the function.

```
const timeCheck = (time) => {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (time > 2399) {
        time -= 2400
    }
    else if (time < 0) {
        time += 2400
        console.log(time)
    }
    var a = time.toString()
    var b=a;
    if (a.length === 1) {
        b = "000" + a
    }
    else if (a.length === 2) {
        b = "00" + a
    }
    else if (a.length === 3) {
        b = "0" + a
    }
    time = b

    resolve(time)


})
```

}

The problem is that there are around 250 different timezones (stored in variables) that need to be used in calling the function 250 times. Here is my dumb solution.

```
timeCheck(EST).then((newEST) => {
        timeCheck(UST).then((newUST)=>{
            res.json({
                "UST": newUST,
                "EST":newEST
            })
        })
    })
```

As you can see I call the function over and over again, and passing the different timezones as a parameter and use promise-chaining. This works but I do not think this is feasible to repeat this process 250 times. Is there a smarter way to do this?

I am calling this function inside an asynchronous function.

```
app.get('/currently',  (req, res) => {
getUST().then( (result) => {...
```

Here is getUST if that helps:

```
const getUST = () => {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const url = "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now"
    request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            return
        }
        const time = response.body.currentDateTime

        const usableTime = time.substring(11, 16).replace(':', '')

        resolve(usableTime)
    })
})
```

}

Comment: Why is a Promise used at all here? The reason is not immediately apparent given the non-async code.

Comment: There is no reason in the code that you show that your `timeCheck()` function should return a promise.  It's entirely synchronous code.  Just return a value.  Problem solved.

Comment: You can chain promises in a loop in order to do something asynchronous 250 times in a row, but there's no reason to use a promise here at all.

Comment: I need to return a Promise because I am calling the function in an asynchronous function. It was either that or a callback function or a Promise and I would rather use a Promise.

Comment: No.  It's entirely synchronous code.  Make it a REGULAR function that returns a value and return it that way.  There's no reason to make the function look like an asynchronous function and there's no reason to call it asynchronously.  You are just making your life more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I think maybe you're confused about some of the terminology in our suggestions.  We're saying to make it a regular function that returns a regular value and call it like you would call any regular synchronous function. As in:  `let value = foo(someInput)`.  We want you to make it a synchronous function that does `return time` at the end and call it like a synchronous function.  No promise, no callback.  Just a regular function.  There is nothing asynchronous here so don't mix that in in any way as it just makes your code more complicated than necessary.

Comment: timeCheck(EST)
        res.json({
            "UST":EST
        })
If I call it like this, it does not return the desirable value.

Comment: I posted an answer to show you the synchronous way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggested code:

```
const timeCheck = (time) => {
    if (time > 2399) {
        time -= 2400
    }
    else if (time < 0) {
        time += 2400
        console.log(time)
    }
    let a = time.toString()
    let b=a;
    if (a.length === 1) {
        b = "000" + a
    }
    else if (a.length === 2) {
        b = "00" + a
    }
    else if (a.length === 3) {
        b = "0" + a
    }
    time = b

    return time;  
}
```

And, then you call it like this:

```
let t = timeCheck(EST);
res.json({ "UST": t });
```

If there's some reason (that I'm not understanding) to call this function multiple times, you can just pass the output of one call to the next call:

```
let t1 = timeCheck(EST);
let t2 = timeCheck(t1);
res.json({ "UST": t2 });
```

If you could explain what you're trying to do by calling it more than once and explain what that function is supposed to do, then we could help you fix that part up too.

Comment: I tried doing that but I am calling the function in an asynchronous function. I edited the code above for you to see where am I calling the function. I hope that helps. Sorry, I am still learning this stuff.

Comment: I edited my post above, with some more information. This function is supposed to make time look in the 24-hour format (like "0012"). Without it, the time will just be '12'. The reason it needs to be called 250 times is that there are approximately that many different timezones that I need to call the function with to make it look presentable in the 24-hour format.

Comment: @DhairyaKhara - Do you now understand how you can just make the function be a regular synchronous function with no promises and no callbacks?  It still makes no sense to me that you need to call the function 250 times in a row, but that's a separate issue.  With a synchronous function, you can just put it inside a `for` loop and call it as many times as you want.

Comment: How do I prove to you that I need this function with a request or a callback. Above, I have given some more information on where I am calling the function. It is inside of a function getUST that uses "request". This getUST is inside app.get(). I tried calling this function synchronously but it does not work.

Comment: @DhairyaKhara - Well, either you're not showing the real code or you are not understanding that you can use an ordinary function like this no matter what else it's inside of because there is no evidence here that you need to make this an asynchronous calling interface.  You can try showing us the entire request handler code that this is part of so we can see the whole flow inside one request handler.  But, you can freely call synchronous code anywhere inside an asynchronous world.

Comment: @DhairyaKhara - The only way you could prove you need this to be an asynchronous interface is to show me asynchronous code that goes inside this function.  Without that, there is no reason for an asynchronous interface, regardless of where it is is called from or how it is used.  You can frreely call a synchronous function from anywhere, even inside other asynchronous code.